# PHP mysqli allowed memory size

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, out-of-memory

I have a web-app running on a paid VPS. No problem there. I'm moving this app to my own dedicated server.

- Current Cloud Server -CS-:
  Centos 6 x86_64; 2 Gb Ram; 2 vCPU
- Virtual on Dedicated Server:
  Centos 7 x86_64; 2 Gb Ram; 2 vCPU

I deployed the PC with the same specs because "if it works okay with that it should work with the same".

On a API's endpoint the current CS returns the correct json. The new Server returns:

> Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes) in /var/www/api/Components/Database.php on line 439

line 439 is:

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);
```

The search results I found here and there were not helpful. Some said upgrade PHP version and 90% of them is set a larger memory limit. ** I did**. I set it to 256M, 512M, 2GB (beyond this there is no ram available), 4GB and 5GB. ** Nada**

This query works ok on the other -and production- server.

New server:

```
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9        

PHP/5.4.16 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
```

CS:

```
 Server: Apache 
 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.22
```

I look at the LENGTH of the base64 being queried. They're 2 images data sent. This size is returned by mysql:

```
select LENGTH(image_base64) from pmv where pmv.model = 1;
```

That is the query. It returns 2 row. Image_base64 is LONGTEXT. There are some others columns but it won't add to the issue.

```
LENGTH(image_base64)
162678
131402
```

It is clearly not close to 4Gb

I can't access php/apache conf on the CS. The only thing I didn't try yet is upgrading PHP from 5.4 to 5.5. Could be it? I'll try to get access to the server on weekend to try out any other ideas.

**Edit #1**

I update the PHP Version to 5.6.9.

Same error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes) in <b>/var/www/api/Components/Database.php</b> on line <b>439</b><br />
```

**Edit #2**

Changing the column type from *longtext* to *mediumtext* seems to work as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121619/allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-4294967296-b)

But why on earth I need to change the column type on this server? As far I can test now, no matter how much info is stored on that column. It will give the error as long as it's a longtext col.

Thanks!

Comment: From the look of the failing filename, and the bind_result, it certainly appears to be doing a database query. I would suggest that the size of the data being returned is the base cause of the issues - making this a SQL issue, not PHP. Do you need to return so much data at once?

Comment: @AlisterBulman mysql returns a base64 of a image to be recreated on client. It real size of the image is ~300K. But PHP is complaining about allocating 4gb

Comment: Just one? What is the SQL?

Comment: It sounds like a software bug handling blob column type. I would upgrade the php to see if it goes away.

Comment: Are you in a class' method ? Or in the global space ?

Comment: @IvanGabriele it's a method of http://saskphp.com/ (I'm using that for the API. Works OK on local, staging, production. But with this dedidacted server is my 2nd attempt to make it work.

Comment: Ok :) And could my other question below help you ?

Answer (score 4):

As explained in [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51386) :

> This is a known limitation of ext/mysqli when using libmysql (always in 5.2 and previous) and when libmysql is enabled with 5.3 . The reason is that the server sends not too specific metadata about the column. This longtext has a max length of 4G and ext/mysqli tries to bind with the max length, to be sure no data loss occurs (data doesn't fit in the bind buffer on C level).

ext/mysqli when using [mysqlnd](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) is free from this bug.

So to fix that, you have 4 solutions :

- You can use a `text` or `mediumtext` instead of a `longblob` or `longtext` to use less memory
- You can try to [enable mysqlnd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13176783/285587) for your current PHP version
- You can upgrade your PHP, as it should have mysqlnd enabled by default
- You can use PDO connector instead of mysqli

Personally, I would go for the third one since having an recent version generally bring you many more advantages if it doesn't oblige you to refactor significant parts of your code.

[And an obvious warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml):

> People, changing the memory_limit by ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); is NOT a solution at all.
>
> Please don't do that. Obviously php has a memory leak somewhere and you are telling the server to just use all the memory that it wants. The problem has not been fixed at all

Comment: put in perspective, it's over 4GB. and yes you really should fix it at that amount

Comment: It does. But the same call to the api on both servers at the same time give different results. It's the same code and database on both ends.

Comment: Also is this bug linked to your table types : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121619/allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-4294967296-b ?

Comment: I'll try that. However it does not explain why it already works on other setup.

Comment: @IvanGabriele 4.4.17 of ... ? I'll try it though

Comment: No sorry I deleted it because that was false : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51386. It has not been patched at least until PHP 5.2.13 but maybe later (via mysqli extension).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @isim  : I corrected my answer, giving more details that will answer the **Edit #2** :)

Comment: I installed php  5.6.9. (current server has 5.5.2). The issue will longtext stand still with this version. The error is on another extension I think.

Comment: :/ Did you try to use PDO ?

Answer (score -1):

As presented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/430516/4777622) SO answer, you could try the following:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
```

---

You should however attempt to find where the memory is going, it is always best fixing than forgetting!

This is even more relevant in this case,  seeing that you have a usage of over 4GB, that is one hell of a memory leak.

Comment: Tried a sec ago. It says the same error. And as the machine only has 2gb ram it can allocate. But the query size is not even close to 4GB

Comment: @Engerlost Take a look please: http://i.gyazo.com/6b932c2c1f9ac3012dce5511aff5ade4.png

Comment: There's no leak on the production server and the data being sent are 2 images. IMO its a bug and the error message makes no sense.

Comment: Very, very strange. I'll take a look into it when I can, I'll get back to you ASAP.

Comment: thanks for looking it up. I'll post more info as I get it. But for now I can't access the server until tomorrow

Comment: Look at edit #2. It's working now. I'm trying to know what kind of impact this change might have