# How to execute large database data in php

Tags: php, mongodb

I have large data in `mongoDB` database, i want to execute in `PHP` and show on chart. but i get  `Fatal error: Allowed memory size`
I even increased the memory of `Ram` by 2048. but i have error
My code:

```
        $dbconn = new MongoClient();
        $db = $dbconn->mydatabase;
        $myObj = $db->collection->find();

        $data = iterator_to_array($myObj);

        asort($data);

        if ($data) {

           $dataseries1 = array();

           $dataseries2 = array();

           foreach ($data as $dataset) {
               array_push( $categoryArray , array( "label" => $dataset["type"] ) );

               array_push( $dataseries1 , array( "value" => $dataset["id"] ) );  
           }

          $arrData["dataset"] = array(
            array("data" => $dataseries1),
            array("data" => $dataseries2)
          ); 

          $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);

          $msChart = new FusionCharts("msline", "demochart", "600", "400", "chart-container", "json", $jsonEncodedData);

          $msChart->render();
       }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Allowed memory size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812919/php-allowed-memory-size)

Comment: Please check this url i hope it's useful ... URL:-https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-increase-a-mongo-db-size