# mysqli -> fetch_object() vs mysqli -> fetch_object('myclass') - Random memory issue

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, out-of-memory

My php script runs fine if I fetch the mysqli result as StdClass. But, I run into random "out of memory" issues when i cast the mysqli result to a user-defined class.

**This always works fine:**

```
while ($O = $result->fetch_object()) {
  $papers[$O -> id] = $O;
}
```

**But this causes an out of memory error at times** (only with this specific database, and error thrown randomly)

```
while ($O = $result->fetch_object('paper')) {
  $papers[$O->id] = $O;
}
```

The error message is `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in D:\programdata\Apache\htDocs\_library\Helper.inc on line 278` (That line number makes no sense. it is a commented line).  Try {} except {} blocks do not catch the error. `php memory_get_usage(true)` returned 7,602,176 Bytes during the last loop (#71 out of 220) before the error.

`System Info`
(Running on Apache 2.4.58 with PHP 5.6 on a Dell PowerEdge R830 with 512GB of RAM and almost nothing else going on in the machine. CPU, RAM usage is under 2% throughout. (The OS is running Windows Server 2016).

To emphasize, this is not repeatable. It works fine sometimes, but not always.  (Using the same code without any changes).

Troubleshooting tried:
I called `$db->store_result()` before calling `fetch_object()`  but that did not help.  Also, I have simplified the paper class to do absolutely nothing, but still get the the out of memory error.

```
    class paper {  
      function __construct() {
      }
    }
```

The database has about 250 rows, but each row is fairly long (about 180 fields with 4 blobs). PHP maxmemory is set to 1.5GB (yes GB) and I confirmed that via phpinfo().

When the error happens `php memory_get_usage(true)` reports only about 9MB memory usage.

The following function shows what I am doing. The `exceptionhandler` is not called when the out of memory error occurs. But, this is not a repeatable issue with other databases.

```
function getData($svr, $usr, $pwd, $db, $table){
    
    $papers = array();
    $db = new mysqli($svr, $usr, $pwd, $db);
        
    try {
      $query = "select * from `$table` where year = 2023 ";
      $result = $db -> query($query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);      
      if (!$result) {
          echo "Query Error: " . $query . "<br>";
          exit;
      }

      while ($O = $result -> fetch_object('paper')) {
        echo memory_get_usage(true) . " Processed {$O -> id}.<br>\r\n ";
        $papers[$O -> id] = $O;
      }
   }
   catch (exception $e) {
     echo "Error: " . $e -> getMessage() . " <br>\r\n";
    }
    return $papers;
}
```

Comment: The only thing you haven't provided is the _exact, full_ error message you receive, with stack trace. You can [edit] your question - thanks

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to Apache?

Comment: Also, providing *the exact code* will not only help you to have this issue resolved but also [required by the rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/285587).

Comment: If you put `echo memory_get_usage() . '<br>';` in the loop, how do you see it increasing in the two versions?

Comment: @ADyson Sample function inserted into the question. Exception Handler not called, so don't know how to get stacktrace.

Comment: @NicoHasse: I do not know whether this is related to Apache, but since there is a randomness to the error I thought it is worth mentioning I am running Apache (2.4.58 on Windows).

Comment: I can't reproduce it https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/42cfcb119ad2db33cfa2977f02465848/php/php82/87ea717786d968a1f7eed42bd3d8602b/

Comment: @Dharman, as I indicated, this is not always reproducible. It only happens with one specific database (that has a lot of fields) and is random even in that case.

Comment: Then this question is not suitable for Stack Overflow. And, to be honest, in its current form it's hardly suitable for anywhere else. Just "the code fails randomly" hardly can give any clue. No actual error message, no reproducible code, zero information on the environment. With the info provided, we can only guess. Like, given you are labeling your problem as "out of memory" but not as "Allowed memory size ... exhausted", I suppose your problem has nothing to do with mysqli, as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13961089/285587

Comment: I have added more details, but understand that helping with random errors is not easy. I wanted to know whether anyone else has seen this behaviour. Since I posted it, it worked for a couple of days, but now back to the error again.  If this is deemed not suitable for stackoverflow, I will delete the question.

Comment: I believe that if you change the blobs size from longblob to just blob, the problem will disappear. Also upgrading PHP version should help.

Comment: Found it at last. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30812980/285587 I bet your mysqli is libmysql based and it must be recompiled with mysqlnd

Comment: Thank you @Your-Common-Sense. Changing longblob to blob made it work (at least at this time. I will wait to see how it goes in the coming days).  Yes, I am using libmysqli. I do not compile any of these, but download them. Look for a mysqlnd dll and see how it goes