# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes) Looked at answer? Still not working

Tags: php, mysql

Recently I've been trying to code a simplistic login system for my website, with a lot of errors I have been facing it seems to be going back and forth in unsurety for what to do.

The error message that I am receiving is `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes) on line 17 of index.php` 
I had a look on stackoverflow to see what the cause of the problem might be, and I tried the answer found here

[Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121619/allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-4294967296-b)

But sadly changing `longtext` to `mediumtext` in phpmyadmin still had no effect, In fact it stopped returning any error_log and just reloaded my webpage! If you head over to beastfox.com You can see that all that happens is when entering my test username and password that I have added to the database (username:Username password:Password) It causes a HTTP ERROR 500.

I am slightly unsure of what to do, since it apparently has something to do with my index.php I have listed the code as shown below,

```
<?php
   include("database.php");
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // Create querystring
      $sql = "SELECT password FROM admin WHERE username = ?";

      // Prepare, bind, execute
       if (!$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli,$sql)) {
    echo "Failed to prepare:".mysqli_error($mysqli);
    return;
}
      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli,$sql);
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_POST['username']);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_password);
      if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
         // Validate password
         if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $user_password)) {
             session_register("username");
             $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;

             header("location: myaccount.php");
            exit;
         } else {
             $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
         }
      mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
      } else {
         $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
      }
   }
?>
```

And according to the error_log it says its due to line 17
(`mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_password);`)

As in the other persons stack overflow here i'll list my version etc

PHP Version: 5.6

libmysql - 5.1.73:

memory_limit: 168M

Thanks a billion if you think you have any ideas on what the problem is!

If anything else is needed I will honestly try anything,

I will keep looking just incase but currently everything I have tried does not seem to be working.

Comment: Find the config file of your php server and increase that limit.

Comment: @SvSv I'd much rather figure out what's causing PHP to attempt to allocate FOUR GIGABYTES.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I could be wrong here, but related to what the error_log stated it is something due to line 17 on my index.php?

Comment: Use some php debugger/profiler.

Comment: @SvSv What you are saying isn't really helping matters to the greatest extent. I have no idea how to use a php debugger and I am not exactly sure on how I am meant to do that,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121619/allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-4294967296-b)

Comment: I don't know if this is your case, but in my case, after unsuccessfully trying all solutions posted, we discover that was related with a problem of discrepances in database.

Answer (score 1):

As already [stated in your linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121619/allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-4294967296-b/18121874#18121874) the problem is binding a result variable for a `TEXT` column.

You don't need a `TEXT` column for your password hash, a sufficient [`VARCHAR(255)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) column will be enough. Change your password hash column to that type.

Comment: Thank you so much! The only problem with doing this (Which I have tried similarly alread,) Is that no error_log is returned in my ftp after doing so, And all it does is reload the page (Or do something) But no error_log is created after clicking Submit.